# Is a static factory method the only way to pass runtime values to a prototype's constructor using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

I have an object to be scoped as a prototype, and the constructor argument values are determined at runtime. It seems to me that I have to use a static factory method to construct an instance of this prototype. Is this true, and where in the documentation might I find it stating that fact? I couldn't find anything discussing constructor values or references determined at runtime. All of the samples have explicitely defined values at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally what needs to be done is:

```
applicationContext.getBean("beanName", new Object[]{arg1, arg2, arg3});

<bean id="beanName" class="my.package.className" scope="prototype">
  <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" value=""/>
  //etc
</bean>
```

If your classes are otherwise spring-free and you don't want that applicationContext dependency mucking them up, then a factory method may be desirable.

You could also use Method Replacement to isolate the spring-dependant code.

Comment: It is interesting this works because the documentation for this method for the args parameter says: "arguments to use if creating a prototype using explicit arguments to a static factory method. It is invalid to use a non-null args value in any other case." That is what made me think that call to getBean could only be used for objects created using static factory methods.

Comment: Ya, I guess the Parameters section of the java doc isn't the most meticulously maintained thing ever :)  The method comment does say it can be either constructor args or factory method args:
"Allows for specifying explicit *constructor arguments* / factory method arguments, overriding the specified default arguments (if any) in the bean definition."

Comment: Thanks for the additional info... I'm just glad it works at this point :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`lookup-method` (4.4.6.1 Lookup method injection)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection%5d). Currently it does not support passing arguments to newly created prototype beans, but [this will soon be possible](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7431).